# Is there any way i can check word entered in search view is in which language

Tags: android, localization, searchview

Is there any way i can check word entered in search view is in which language  i.e English or Hindi or another language.
I have to show result according to the input word but unable to check which language is used by keyboard to enter word.
ust to be more clear, I need to recognize the language the user types and not the phone's locale.

For example, my phone is in English and let's say my keyboard is in Russian, the getDefault() returns "en", but I need to have "ru" at that point.

I do not know if this is available out of the box from android, maybe an approach to detect the string's character codes and see if is in English alphabet or in another. Any points on this?

I imagine something like 
if character belongs to K then is English 
(where K is the essemble of english characters)

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
    String lang="english";      
    for (int k = 0; k < Character.codePointCount(query, 0, query.length()); k++) {
        int c = query.codePointAt(k);
        if (c >= 0x0900 && c <= 0x0960) {
            lang = "hindi";
            break;
        }
    }
```